# Извлечение данных из запроса XMLHttpRequest.send

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Есть кнопка при нажатии которой происходит ajax запрос на контроллер с передачей данных методом post

```
<button id="telephone_button" data-id="1">Show the phone number</button>

<script>
    var elem = document. querySelector('#telephone_button');
    elem.addEventListener('click',function () {
        var id = this.dataset.id;
        ajaxSend(id,this);
    });

    function ajaxSend(id,elem) {

        const req =new XMLHttpRequest();

        req.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var unswer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            elem.outerHTML = '<a id="telephone_button"  href="tel:'+unswer.tel+'">'+unswer.tel+'</a>';
        });

        req.open('POST','http://localhost/WebsiteProject/ajax/contact',true );
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var param = 'id='+id;
        req.send(param);

    }
</script>
```

В результате этого, когда функция контроллера на сервере запускается, oнa не может извлечь переданные параметры(через $_POST['id'])

Update

Незнаю что я исправил но это у меня заработало.

html,js:

```
 <button id="telephone_button" data-id="<?php echo $postItem['author_id']; ?>">Show the phone number</button>
<script>
    var elem = document. querySelector('#telephone_button');
    elem.addEventListener('click',function () {
        var id = this.dataset.id;
        ajaxSend(id,this);
    });

    function ajaxSend(id,elem) {
        console.log('id=', id);
        const req =new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var unswer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            elem.outerHTML = '<a id="telephone_button"  href="tel:'+unswer.tel+'">'+unswer.tel+'</a>';
        });
        var param = 'id='+id;
        req.open('POST','http://localhost/WebsiteProject/ajax/contact',true );
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        console.log(param);
        req.send(param);

    }
</script>
```

php:

```
class AjaxController{

function actionContact(){


    $userId=$_POST['id'];
    $tel = USER::getUserPhone($userId);
    $arr = array( 'tel' => $tel['tel']);
    echo(json_encode($arr));
    return true;
```

}
}

Comment: кавычка `'` должна стоять *перед* закрывающей квадратной скобкой `$_POST['id']`

Comment: Сорри, это сейчас опечатался)

Comment: `function ajaxSend(id,elem) { console.log('id=', id); ...` - что в консоли браузера?

Comment: console.log('id=', id); // id= 2

Comment: "oнa не может извлечь переданные параметры" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: req.send - запускает нужную функцию в контроллере (это точно). Но при распечатке массивов $_GET, $_POST видно что они пустые. Ответ же из этой функции отсылаеться нормально.